# Is Mark 4:36-39 a fulfillment of Psalm 144:7?

Tags: psalms, mark, authorial-intent

NIV | **Psalm 144:7**

> "Reach down your hand from on high; deliver me and rescue me
> **from the mighty waters, from the hands of foreigners**"

If hands of foreigners could pull on a boat like mighty waters (Psalm 144:7), then the does the miracle in Mark 4:36-39 simply demonstrate Jesus told the "other [foreigner] boats with them" to stop shouting / reaching for the disciples' boat?

NIV | **Mark 4:36-39**

> Leaving the crowd behind, they took him along, just as he was, in the boat. **[There were also other boats with him.]** A furious squall came up, and the waves broke over the boat, so that it was nearly swamped. Jesus was in the stern, sleeping on a cushion. The disciples woke him and said to him, “Teacher, don’t you care if we drown?” He got up, rebuked the wind and **said to the [foreigners] , “Quiet! Be still!”** Then the wind died down and it was completely calm.

- Is Mark 4:36-39 a fulfillment of Psalm 144:7?

Comment: Looking through the parallel Bibles on biblehub.com, I am unable to find any "foreigner's waves" in the text.

Comment: Is the word for "waves" the same as "mighty waters"? If "hands of foreigners" are like "mighty waves" in Psalm 144, could the "waves" in Mark 4 be a metaphor describing "hands of foreigners" in the other boats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Psalms 144 is a psalm of David, for rescue and prosperity. To [fulfill means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fulfill)

> to bring to an end

Are you asking if David was rescued then in Mark 4:36-39? That's not making much sense to me.

Also, in Psalms 144:11

> Rescue me and save me from the hand of foreigners, (...)

the image of the foreigns as floodwaters isn't present anymore. So what I extract from it is that the initial image was just to convey a certain degree of chaos - Proverbs 8:29

> When He set a boundary for the sea
>
> So that the water would not violate His command,
>
> When He marked out the foundations of the earth;

The only relation I can see between the two passages is found in the comments on my KJV study bible about Mark 4:35-41

> Jesus is the Lord of nature as much as He is the Lord of individuals.

Comment: Thank you for keeping scripture in context!